# different names in input type radio via PHP

Tags: php

i have a code with foreach which reading themes from database. I want them to be writeable to another database (classic $_POST['']; method)
My code for foreach looks like

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
     <input type="radio" name="<?php $article['tema_id']; ?>"> 
       <?php echo $article['nazov_temy']; ?> <small> - <?php echo $article['obsah_temy']; ?></small><br />
       <?php } ?>
     <input type="submit" name="odoslat" />
</form>
```

And code with post should be something like (i haven't wrote code for that yet)

```
if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

    if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
        $error = "All field are required";
    } else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO temy (nazov_temy, obsah_temy, tema_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

        $query->bindValue(1, $title);
        $query->bindValue(2, $content);
        $query->bindValue(3, time());

        $query->execute();
```

Comment: do you pass only one value of `$article['tema_id']` to your DB?? I can see `$article['tema_id']` is the name but if you have only one value that you select and pass to the DB please use common name and use `<select>` box to select one. do you want to send multiple article to DB at a time? TO get value based on name you should have static name or a comman name for any kind of input fields.

Comment: i need to use radio because user should select only one theme and theme should be write into database. I need to post that whole nazov_temy to database and only-one method i know is based on name from form

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment above 
**HTML**

```
//Inside foreach
<input type="radio" name="selected_theme" value="<?php $article['tema_id']; ?>">
```

**PHP**

```
$theme = $_POST['selected_theme'];
```

If you want to select only one theme and pass that to the next PHP processor page. Put a common name for all the radio elements generated using `foreach` loop

**For example:** the **above** `Foreach` loop will generate HTML elements like this

```
<input type="radio" name="selected_theme" value="1"> 
<input type="radio" name="selected_theme" value="2"> 
<input type="radio" name="selected_theme" value="3"> 
.........
```

But you can use select box too instead of radio like following:

```
<select name='selected_theme'>
      <?php foreach....... ?>
      <option value="<?php $article['tema_id']; ?>">Theme name</option>
       ......
</select>
```

and PHP same way.

```
$selected_theme_id = $_POST['selected_theme'];
```